# How can I add HTML and CSS specs to this simple Spring project?

Tags: java, html, json, spring-boot, frontend

I've been playing around with some Spring Boot tutorials (most importantly [Building A Restful Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)). I am getting output as JSON in my browser.

I would like to know how I can read the JSON into HTML & CSS to make it look nice. My three java files are 'Application.java' 'Greeting.java' and 'GreetingController.java'.

I don't want to overload with my code, but basically I made it so that when I enter 
localhost:8080/greetings/add?name=User ('User' can be whatever) 
it adds the user to an Arraylist, and then at localhost:8080/greetings it prints out all the greetings, like this:

[image]

How do I get it to be read into HTML & CSS, so I could get something like this (different content of course, but just a table that takes in the JSON)?

[image]

Here's the github link if interested: https://github.com/josephmalisov/SpringBootGreetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring guide "[Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)" provides an answer.  In your controller, add your object to your model and then return the name of a template page.  e.g. 
[`model.addAttribute("name",name);`](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/com/example/servingwebcontent/GreetingController.java#L13)

Loops in Thymeleaf are an easy way to build your table.   Include your github repo and I'll send you a pull request (maybe).

Comment: Added the github link. Thank you for the response!